# Using awk to calculate and print average scores for each row

Tags: linux, unix, awk

Use the awk command

1. Using the grades.txt file print out the first and last name of each student and
   calculate/print the grade in percentage that they currently have (assuming equal
   weights for each assignment).

grades.txt file

```
FN LN Lab HW1 HW2 HW3 HW4
Ryan Slaven 1 1 0 1 1
Jephthah Eustathios 0 1 0 1 0
Andreas Saša 1 0 1 0 1
Godofredo Gerard 1 1 1 1 1
Edwin Babur 1 0 1 1 1
Ahmad Marin 0 0 0 0 0
Jett Marko 1 1 0 1 1
```

My answer for it is:

```
awk '{sum=0;for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) sum+=$i; print $1, $2, (NF>2?sum/(NF-2):0)*100}' grades.txt
```

However, for the output next to FN and LN it shows 0. How could I remove the 0, or make it say "Average"? Alternatively, how could I delete the row?

Also, is there a better way to solve the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk 'NR == 1 { print $1, $2, "Average"; next }    # Print a heading row
     NF > 2  { sum=0; for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) sum+=$i; print $1, $2, (sum/(NF-2))*100 }' \
     grades.txt
```

Simply process the first row differently; the `next` skips the rest of the script on the first line.  For other rows with more than two fields, print the name and average.  It would be possible to report on rows where `NF <= 2` if required.

Sample output:

```
FN LN Average
Ryan Slaven 80
Jephthah Eustathios 40
Andreas Saša 60
Godofredo Gerard 100
Edwin Babur 80
Ahmad Marin 0
Jett Marko 80
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{print $1, $2, (NR>1 ? 100*gsub(1,1)/(NF-2) : "Average")}' file
FN LN Average
Ryan Slaven 80
Jephthah Eustathios 40
Andreas Saša 60
Godofredo Gerard 100
Edwin Babur 80
Ahmad Marin 0
Jett Marko 80
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @J Earls said and then some:

```
$ awk 'NF>2{sum=0;for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) sum+=$i; print $1, $2, (NR>1?sum/(NF-2)*100:"Average")}' grades.txt
FN LN Average
Ryan Slaven 80
Jephthah Eustathios 40
Andreas Saša 60
Godofredo Gerard 100
Edwin Babur 80
Ahmad Marin 0
Jett Marko 80
```

Explained:

```
NF>2 {                 # for records with field count more than two
    sum=0
    for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) 
        sum+=$i
    print $1, $2, (NR>1?sum/(NF-2)*100:"Average") # NR=1 print "Average", else the average
}
```

EDIT:

With those empty records between the actual records of data gone, you can remove that condition `NF>2`, leaving you with:

```
$ awk '{sum=0;for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) sum+=$i; print $1, $2, (NR>1?sum/(NF-2)*100:"Average")}' grades.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

Only run your awk command on lines where `NF>2`:

```
awk 'NF>2 {…}'
```